# Inner / static nested classes in Java - outer class' name

Tags: java, inner-classes, static-classes

I'd like to ask when it's required to explicitly write the name of the outer class when referring to the inner class or static nested class.

Ex:

```
class B {
    static class Inner {
        int a = 10;
    }
}

class Test extends B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        Inner obj = new Inner();
        System.out.println(obj.a);
    }
}
```

What I'd like to ask is under which circumstances it's needed to write:

```
B.Inner obj = new B.Inner();
```

instead of

```
Inner obj = new Inner();
```

Comment: You say *Inner classes* in your title but your example shows a static nested class. Based on the initialization syntax you've provided I'm guessing you're asking about static nested classes, is that true?

Comment: Yes, I was interested in the problem being applied to both - inner classes and static nested classes

Comment: It's confusing that you named a non-inner class `Inner`. Do you think that's really a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

For *static nested classes* (as G. Fiedler has mentioned in his answer) you can write `new Inner()` when you are within the scope of `B`.

You can also directly refer to `Inner` from within `Test` because it extends `B`.

In all other cases you need to say `B.Inner` and `new B.Inner()`.

*Inner classes* - which are not `static` by definition - are initialized differently. Let's look at this example `B`:

```
class B {
    public class Inner {
        ...
    }
}
```

Inner classes are always tied to an instance of the outer class. That means that in this case there has to be an instance of `B` for us to be able to instantiate `Inner`. So let's do that:

```
B b = new B();
```

*I'm by the way assuming we are currently somewhere outside of the scope of `B`*

In order to create an instance of `Inner` we use our instance of `B` and write:

```
B.Inner inner = b.new Inner();
```

If we were inside of `B` (in a **non-static** method) we could, however, simply write

```
Inner inner = new Inner();
```

because we - or rather the compiler - know(s) that an instance of `B` has to exist for this `inner` to be tied to.

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside the scope of `class B` then `new Inner()` can be used. Outside of `class B` `new B.Inner()` must be used.

Comment: This isn't true because the class `Inner` in the OP's example is a static nested class. So `new B()` (note the parentheses!) would not work.